# How can I overcome the error "unknown parent" when applying a Mercurial bundle.

Tags: mercurial, repository, bundle

I bundle changes from one repository, email them to another machine and apply them there to a repository (for a workflow description see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23122883/65889)).

Suddenly I get the following error message (when applying a bundle with a command like `hg unbundle -u "bundle_123.hg"`):

```
adding changesets transaction abort!
rollback completed 
abort: 00changelog.i@24ecac5680c1: unknown parent!
```

How can I apply this bundle despite the "unknown parent"? I hoped for a `--force`option, but `unbundle` doesn't have one...

Or can I avoid this error in an other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: you can't unbundle this bundle, because autonomous changesets are impossible in Mercurial

You don't have parent of 24ecac5680c1 (?) CSET in destination repository (while you **must** have it) - your bundle is bad and you selected wrong base on bundling

Comment: ...but wait: the problem might be that I **forgot** to apply an **intermediate** bundle... then the parent needed for the later bundle isn't transfered!

Comment: @halloleo - for exactly this reason I recommended (in your first question) always use **oldest base**

Comment: Aaaah, I have so many problems syncing 2 repos via bundles: I got again an "unkown parent" error, although I *always* put all changes in the bundle from a marker (which I move after bundling to the tip). It all must go pear-shaped when when I have changes on *both* repos in parallel...

Comment: @halloleo - bundle **full repo** every time - less operations, less errors, no headache

Comment: Not an option: repo contains lots of big binaries I only want to transfer once!