# Timestamp-based automatic merge in Mercurial

Tags: merge, mercurial, timestamp

I want to use Mercurial for a email-based sync system (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23122883/65889)).

I have played around with sending bundles back and forth ad applying them to the repositories to be synced. But I often get merge conflicts which I have to resolve manually.

But they could be resolved easily automatically: **I just want the newer file to replace the older one.**

Is it possible to set up a merge-tool in Mercurial that does exactly that: When I `hg pull` a bundle it updates to the file with the newer time stamp?

Answer (score 2):

1. When you pull or unbundle new changesets in repository **must not intersect** with done in parallel (you'll get new head only) - I can't see why you can have merge on pull (uncommited local changes? Commit before pull!)
2. If your merge-conflicts appear on merge heads (when you merge local head into tip after pull) and you prefer to have tip version of **conflicted files** and abandon local changes you can use merge with `--tool=internal:local` option
3. If you prefer dummy-merge, i.e abandon **all local changes from all files**, you can use [this trick](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#mergemineortheir) from Mercurial wiki

Comment: He is correct, these are your options. I wanted to tell you that you could use a custom `[merge-tools]` to check the timestamps when doing a merge, but I think the files that receive for comparison are temporary files, and do not keep the original timestamps anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I do not want that **all** local files get abandoned, rather that the external file gets copied in when its timestamp is newer, while the local file stays when its timestamp is newer.

Comment: @halloleo - bundle doesn't contain timestamps of files in included changesets, you have to re-think policy

Comment: Aha, that's the situation! This means my whole idea of a hg-based syncing mechanism cannot work like this... Thanks heaps!